# Discordjs TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a bot for ddiscord and I can't solve this error:
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const config = require('./config.json')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const privateMessage = require('./private-message'); 
const test = require('./test.js')

const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN'];





client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in.`);
});
```

and this is the complete error:

```
D:\user\Bots\dadobot2801\a\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (D:\user\Bots\dadobot2801\a\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
    at new Client (D:\user\Bots\dadobot2801\a\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\user\Bots\dadobot2801\a\test.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\user\Bots\dadobot2801\a\index.js:10:14) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add the required intent to your bot? https://discord.com/developers/applications

Answer (score 0):

[image: image1]

I had this problem before so i know how to fix it. You need to enable these 3 intents as seen in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. npm uni discord.js
2. npm i discord.js@12.5.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).